# What is Unix for the OpenVMS DUMP command?

Tags: openvms, dump

In [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) the [DUMP](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/9996/9996pro_67.html) command:

> Displays the contents of a file, a directory, a disk volume, a
>   magnetic tape volume, or a CD-ROM volume in decimal, hexadecimal,
>   octal format, ASCII, or formatted data structures.

This is frequently used when a file is not a simple text file where the content has a mixture of data types such as strings and integers.

What is the Unix/Linux command for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few options.

- [`od`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) should be available on POSIX systems, so most Unix and Linux variants will have it. That command has a slew of options to control the output format.
- `hexdump` (from [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) on my distro) is my favorite for a quick inspection (`hexdump -C`), but it's not available everywhere.
- `xxd` (installed with Vim) is great too - especially since it allows you to convert to a human-readable hex format, and to convert *back* to binary. So that gives you a pretty simple hex editor.

Comment: +1 for xxd. It's not available everywhere, but that's the one you want to use.